# how find coordinates of cells

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

For example I have a:

```
1x11 cell
 [] []  3   []  []  []  []  []  1   []  []
```

How can I do to find coordinates of cells non empty?

like `res=[1,3;1,9]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the function [`isempty`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html) to each cell's contents via [`cellfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html), and then get the column and row indices of the cells that gave `false` (that is, were not empty) using the two-output version of [`find`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
x = {[] []  3   []  []  []  []  []  1   []  []}
[ii, jj] = find(~cellfun(@isempty, x))
res = [ii(:) jj(:)];
```

Comment: Ooh ok thanks !! I'm not used to manipulating cells with matlab at all. You are my savior today, thank you very much and thank you for your explanations I understand all the better the finality :-D